# make three div class into same line

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to know if possible, how to aling on a same line the  containing 'Quality Analyst', 'Celestica Sdn Bhd' and 'MYR 2xxx' without changing HTML

html :

```
<div class="colMiddle resume-detail-item-middle">
    <div class="pageRow resume-detail-position long-text-word">Quality Analyst</div>
    <div class="pageRow resume-company-location long-text-word">Celestica (AMS) Sdn. Bhd.</div>
    <div class="pageRow resume-detail-item-inner resume-margin">
        <div class="resume-detail-item-inner-left resume-summary-heading resume-label">Monthly Salary</div>
        <div class="resume-detail-item-inner-middle resume-summary-heading">MYR&nbsp;2,515</div>

... missing html
```

In a more clearer way :

```
<div class="outter-containement">
    <div class="inner-content-1">inner-content-1</div>
    <div class="inner-content-2">inner-content-2</div>
    <div class="inner-content-3">
        <div class="sub-inner-content-3-1">sub-inner-content-3-1</div>
        <div class="sub-inner-content-3-2">sub-inner-content-3-2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i align on a single line inner-content-1, inner-content-2 and sub-inner-content-3-2

http://jsfiddle.net/K58S2/14/

Comment: What's with all the down voting?

Comment: This JsFiddle is a little ridiculous to help with...

Comment: i replaced jsFiddle for an indented one

Comment: I think you have already got a hint of the solutions i.e. to use display:inline-block or float:left. Did you try them?

Comment: Greetings new user####, i edited your question and need to make sure i understood what you want to express. You can just [edit] it and roll it back to previous version if it's not OK with you. Also, you are invited to see http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: @Im not the one give down vote.

Comment: one more question, how can give auto " , " after the position title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend changing the HTML like so: http://jsfiddle.net/K58S2/11/

However you said without changing the HTML, so here is a CSS answer: http://jsfiddle.net/K58S2/7/

```
.resume-detail-position, .resume-company-location{
   float:left; 
   width:auto;
   clear:none;
   margin-right:7px;
}
.resume-company-location{
   margin-top:1px;   
}
```

Comment: OP is about 'without' changing html

Comment: That's why I provided a CSS solution also :) however my recommendation is to fix the HTML, and that is why I provided both.

Comment: Hi, appreciated with your answer, could you please clarify how can I add a "," after "Quality Analyst"

Comment: You cannot add content with CSS, only style content. Use html. Technically you could use JavaScript, but I can't imagine the circumstances under which you would.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the style property `display:inline-block;` to all three classes

For example:

```
.colMiddle {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This could have adverse effects on the other elements with this class throughout the website. Additionally it does not work due to the width:100% and clear:both which are applied to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline;` to each `div` that's needs to be in line.

Comment: Whoever keeps downvoting these answers- can you please share your take so we can find a best option here? Thank you much

Answer (score 0):

A better bet would be throw them in spans, like so:

```
<span> CONTENT </span>
<span> CONTENT </span>
<span> CONTENT </span>
```

However, if you insist on aligning divs, something like this would suffice:

```
<style type="text/css">
.example { float:left; }
</style>
<div class="example"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="example"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="example"> CONTENT </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i undersood your question, you will have to add a `margin-right:` to the outter container, the same width reserved of the container for 'MYR 2xxx'. Then, `position:absolute; right:0;` your container for 'MYR 2xxx', it will fit in.

For making your dividers aligned on a row, you will have to study your css and re-design it, because actually, your dividers take 100% width and `clear:both;` so you will have to manage all this because even if you attempt to `float:left` the containers, it won't work.

So, a short answer, yes you can do it with only .css. But be prepared for tricky css re-writing/overwriting.

An other aproach would be javascript, by removing your 'MYR 2xxx' container and replacing it in the normal flow, after 'Celestica Sdn Bhd'. For that approach, study jquery `.detatch()`, `.append()`, `.appendTo()` and `insertAfter()`.

It would look like [jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/K58S2/15/) :

```
 $('.resume-detail-item-inner-middle.resume-summary-heading').insertAfter($('.pageRow.resume-company-location.long-text-word') );
```

But still you will have to rework your css.